# PCL: X and Y values are changed when pcd file is loaded by PCL library

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I want to load point cloud data using PCL. I could load sample data on tutorial correctly, but when I try with my data, the value of pcd file was changed to very small value.

Terminal output image
 [image]

The actual value is like 3603538.71629 but when PCL reads this file it becomes very small values.
This is my pcd file.

```
# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION .7
FIELDS x y z cluster
SIZE 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F F
COUNT 1 1 1 1
WIDTH 14937
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 14937
DATA binary
# POINT_X;POINT_Y;Count;Cluster
3603538.71629;5794698.05946;1;4
3605159.73611;5792213.47052;1;20
3605158.44424;5792230.86339;1;20
3605158.97718;5792221.85844;1;20
3605152.30217;5792232.17992;1;20
3604558.82308;5793345.02318;1;55
3604944.90684;5794341.30959;1;56
```

This is my pcd_read.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("xyzc-Cloud.pcd", *cloud) == -1) //* load the file
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file xyzc-Cloud.pcd \n");
    return (-1);
  }
  std::cout << "Loaded "
            << cloud->width * cloud->height
            << " data points from xyzc-Cloud.pcd with the following fields: "
            << std::endl;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)  
    std::cout << "    " << cloud->points[i].x
              << " "    << cloud->points[i].y
              << " "    << cloud->points[i].z << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
'''
```

Environment:
macOS ver 10.14.16

Answer (score 1):

I think you are seeing corruption because of your coordinate data being improperly formatted. The fields are supposed to be space or tab delimited, whereas you have a character `;`.

Quote from the [docs](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php):

> Storing point cloud data in both a simple ascii form with each point on a line, **space or tab separated**, without any other characters on it, as well as in a binary dump format, allows us to have the best of both worlds: simplicity and speed, depending on the underlying application.

This is confirmed by looking at the [reader source](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/src/pcd_io.cpp) where the lines are split using the following. Your semi-colon will lead to invalid splitting and subsequent float extraction. The function does not return an error for improper formatting, which is why your code still works, albeit incorrectly.

```
boost::split (st, line, boost::is_any_of ("\t\r "), boost::token_compress_on);
```

Therefore, answer is to format your .pcd body data with space delimiters.

---

Also as @UlrichtEckhardt comments you're mixing and matching intended output formats:

Replace

```
DATA binary
```

with

```
DATA ascii
```

Comment: Also, I'd question whether `DATA binary` makes sense when followed by textual tuple representations.